# get a pid using a list of handles for a particular process

Tags: autohotkey, handle

[image] Please refer to this.

https://pastebin.com/LTPiZUGs
This script gets a handle list of a process.

Can I use this script to get the name or pid of the process that holds the handle of a process? If possible, please give us sample code.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a script a while ago which should contain all the necessary pieces to do what you want. The script as is simply lists all file handles and their processes.

The script is too long to paste it in this answer, so please refer to:
https://github.com/T-vK/WhoLockedMe

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not what I want.
For example. When you open the process with the Cheat Engine, 
This does not show the cheat engine on the handle list.

Comment: What do you expect from me? I'm not going to write all the code for you. The script contains everything necessary to retrieve all handles form a process. Changing the code filter out the handles that _you_ need instead of the file handles is your job.